Improve BigQuery's canvas query generation
In BigQuery, there is a new feature called Canvas that allows SQL query generation based on natural language sentences using Gemini. However, the generated queries are often not accurate unless precise information, such as the specific fields for joins or where statements, is provided.
I'm wondering if there's a way to supply Gemini with information related to my tables to improve the accuracy of the query generation. According to BigQuery's documentation, "BigQuery data canvas works with Dataplex metadata to identify appropriate tables based on natural language. BigQuery data canvas uses Gemini to find your data, create SQL, generate charts, and create data summaries." Unfortunately, the documentation does not specify how to better identify fields to join on, and there isn't more information to specify which metadata is used. Furthermore, adding metadata to Dataplex requires using the Dataplex Metadata API, which is not as user-friendly as many other Google interfaces.
I have metadata in Looker (LookML), where several joins are made between tables/views. I believe this metadata could be useful, but I have not found a way to leverage it for improving query generation in BigQuery Canvas. Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to achieve this?
I tried adding table schemas in BigQuery and giving an overview of tables in Dataplex, but it didn't help.
I also checked out Data Catalog Metadata, Dataplex Metadata, Entries, and Entry Groups in Dataplex, but these options either don't seem useful or are too complicated for me since I am not really supposed to develop using Google APIs...

Your analysis is right and your suggestion are good. I also did the same to the eng team during the private preview of the feature. There is a team named NL2SQL in charge to improve the query generation accuracy (and usefulness!). I have no news since then, but I hope it will be improved soon!
